# Каким образом обычно подключается шаблон дизайна сайта к контенту?

Tags: html, css

Я не верю, что для каждой страницы копируется фал с шаблоном и во внутрь вставляется сам контент, в таком случае если потребуется сделать изменения в самом шоблоне эти изменения придется дублировать на каждой странице.

Мне нужен сам принцип прикрепления шаблона к файлам контента. И какой код для этого используют.

Comment: Вот тут отвечал на аналогичный вопрос: http://hashcode.ru/questions/142422/html-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5
Оно?

Comment: Во фреймворках, построенных на MVC (yii framework в примере), это делается в сущности View. Для CMS системы это Theme (тема, шаблон). Скачайте какую-нибудь тему скажем с http://drupal.org/project/themes (темы для Drupal) и посмотрите в код.

Comment: @Krezvaa, для информации: шаблон может вообще не быть файлом на диске, и копировать его в принципе никуда невозможно :)

Answer (score 1):

Читайте, ковыряйте исходники, изучайте.

[MVC](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller) Для общего понимания темы

[Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/ru/what.is.smarty.tpl) Один из самых популярных шаблонизаторов для PHP

[DLE](http://dle-news.ru/) Ну очень простая ЦМС, со smarty-подобным шаблонизатором, может быть полезно поковырять исходники, чтобы на простейшем примере увидеть как это все работает.